# Move mail boxes data to external drive on Mac Mail on Mavericks

Tags: mac, mail.app, email

I have read, and search one blog to another, one question that seamed what I wanted. I do not want to move the whole Mailbox or configuration to another drive but want to free up some disk space by moving some mail boxes/folders to another drive without losing the mails. The closest to what I want are these steps:

1. Close Mac Mail
2. Move the .mbox folders that one wants on ~/Library/Mail/V2/Mailboxes to external drive
3. Do a Symlink on ~/Library/Mail/V2/Mailboxes pointing to /Volumes/<drive name>/<location of .mbox folder> (doing on a Terminal Window or by right-clicking on the folders on Finder)
4. Open Mail and the Boxes should be using the ones on the HD

I've done this on Mail on OS X Mavericks. The Boxes are there but no mails can be read. Can someone help me if I'm missing steps or have to do it differently on Mavericks?

Comment: What does `ls -la ~/Library/Mail/V2/` show?

Answer (score 1):

I believe Mail updates the .mbox file each time it closes which basically overwrites the symlink.

You could consider trying to symlink in the other direction as spelled out [here on Mac OSX Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/comment.php?mode=view&cid=38759) or alternatively symlink a parent directory of the .mbox instead since it does not get rewritten.